# Where does the conditional part of conditional logistic regression come from?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am trying to fully understand where the conditional part of the term conditional logistic regression comes from. In particular, I can't seem to find a source in the literature that emphasizes that you are conditioning on some sort of sufficient statistic for the stratum parameters. Additionally, I can't seem to find a source that explains the intuition behind conditioning on such statistics.

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5514/queries-on-conditional-logistic-regression

Answer (score 1):

I think **Conditional Logistic Regression** part of ***[Categorical Data Analysis by Alan Agresti](http://as.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470463635.html)*** will be helpful in this situation.